# How to show numeric keyboard (tab from simple text keyboard) on an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am implementing an Android app in which I have an `EditText` which I want to fill with text. The values that the users will enter are like this : "12bread","45drink", etc.
I want to make it easier for the user and when he focuses on the `EditText` I first show him the numeric tab of the standard text keyboard.

[image: Text Keyboard -> 123]

The problem is that I want to do that without obligating the user to press on 123 first:

[image: Text Keyboard]

Using `inputType="number"` or other programatically methods just result in showing the numeric keypad but I can't return to text keypad within a single click after so that he can use chars also for the value.

[image]

Can anyone tell me if there is a solution to solve this? I have searched and searched and no Q/A matched my case and till now nobody said it is impossible. So I am still hoping for a miracle.
The images presented above are just to show the types of keyboards.

Comment: I doubt this can be done -- and even if you found a hack, there's a chance that another keyboard won't support it. I would consider changing the input mode for your app, however to separate the numbers from the letters. If there's always two digits + letters, you could use a `TextWatcher` to advance from the digit-entry to the letters.

Comment: Did you try following in your `onCreate()`: `etTest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTest);
etTest.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` ?

Comment: I agree with 323go. Start with numeric input type, then run a callback through TextWatcher that detects the user has input 2 numbers then programmatically change the keyboard input type.

Comment: @323go - My goal is to find out if it is possible; the values are not always the same: I could have "4MAIN" and "459SECOND". Using listener would just slow the treatment

Comment: @ShobhitPuri - your suggestion just opens the numeric keyboard; the one I said it is not helpful.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, that actually wouldn't work. The InputType is only observed on opening the IME, it will not actually change it once it's already visible. So my suggestion remains -- make it two adjacent input boxes, first for numbers, second for text or alpha-numeric, and then the user starts in digit-mode, tap [Next] and is off to the regular keyboard. FWIW, a TextWatcher does not slow things down unless it's poorly coded.

Comment: @323go Interesting! Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this might work. Use a "onTextChangeListener" in your EditText so when the lenght or some determinative string has been recorded the keyboard will switch. I Have a project where I do something like this:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        //Check after user finished writting
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //if the lenght of the editText is > 3...
            if (s.length()>=3){
                yourTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    }

                }

    });
```